# cascade delete on nullable foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm using Entity Framework 6. I have cascade delete set on a foreign key which is nullable. Apparently the cascade delete doesn't seem to be working. It just sets the foreign key to null instead of cascade deleting. Why is this and how can I get around this issue?

Comment: Shar your code. Cascade delete is default mechanism of handling deleting related entities. See this [EF cascade delete](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: I realize that. Cascade delete works for me in other circumstances except this one where foreign key is nullable.

Comment: @Riz ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, not a data access library. It has nothing to do with loading or deleting data.

Comment: @Riz post your code, both the table schemas (especially the FK creation statements) and the context configuration. You're asking people to guess the settings you've used. `SET TO NULL` requires an explicit configuration, it's not something that happens by accident. The *default* is to refuse to delete a parent record if there are any child records

Answer (score 1):

Cascade on delete automatically deletes dependent records or sets null to ForeignKey columns when the parent record is deleted in the database. So if you want a way to work around your problem, try this:

```
context.RelatedTables.RemoveRange(context.RelatedTables.Where(c => c.FKId == id));
```